# Jsreport how to fill the table with data

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsreport

im trying to to fill a table with data to export it in pdf using jsreport
but i couldnt manage to do it .
This is the html file :

```
<h1>test{{test}}</h1>
<table class='table striped'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>ShipAddress</th>
                <th>ShipCity</th>
                <th>ShipCountry</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{items.order}}</td>
                <td>{{items.addr}}</td>
                <td>{{items.city}}</td>
                <td>{{items.country}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And this is the data :

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "order": "65854",
        "addr": "test 1",
        "city": "2fc2",
        "country": "2fc2"
    },
    {
        "order": "75757",
        "addr": "azerty",
        "city": "2fc2",
        "country": "2fc2"
    },
    {
        "order": "65575784",
        "addr": "tst",
        "city": "2fc2",
        "country": "2fc2"
    }
]
}
```

I've tried a lot of things but i couldnt manage to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
<h1>test{{test}}</h1>
<table class='table striped'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>OrderID</th>
            <th>ShipAddress</th>
            <th>ShipCity</th>
            <th>ShipCountry</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {{#each items}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{order}}</td>
            <td>{{addr}}</td>
            <td>{{city}}</td>
            <td>{{country}}</td>
        </tr>
       {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsreport.net/learn/handlebars

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).